# How to display an alert using jquery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display an alert using jQuery like this:

```
  <div id="js-flash-container" class="alert fade in" style="display: none">
          <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
          <span id="js-flash-message"></span>
      </div>
```

Then I have a function that I call to inject the alert class and text:

```
var _flashMessage = function(level, message){
        $("#js-flash-message").html(message);
        $("#js-flash-container").addClass("alert-" + level).show();
    };
```

This works fine, but after displaying the message once, you cannot display it again.

I think it is because the actual DOM gets removed once the message is closed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: _Just add data-dismiss="alert" to your close button to automatically give an alert close functionality. Closing an alert **removes it from the DOM**._ - I believe you need to reconstruct the whole thing

Comment: @AlonEitan Look at my html above, I already have that data-dismiss on the close button?

Comment: @Blankman you don't want to use `data-dismiss` because it removes the element from the DOM. You can remove that attribute and use something like `$('.close').on('click',function() {
  $(this).closest('.alert').hide();
})` and it will hide the alert.

Comment: @Blankman I have added more detailed description in my answer

Comment: @Blankman Did my answer helped or should I remove it?

Comment: @AlonEitan I used what Michael cokier suggested.